# Get `UITableViewCell` indexPath using `UIScrollView`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` which contains a `UICollectionView`. The `UITableViewCell` also contains a `UIPageControl`. I want to change the dots as the `UICollectionView` is swiped. I am using

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

to get the current visible `UICollectionViewCell`. But my problem is that since the `UICollectionView` lies in `UITableViewCell` to fetch the reference to the collectionView I require the indexPAth of the current table view in which collection cell is being swiped. How can I do this?

I want to do this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Change the dots
    CustomTableCell *tableCell = [self.currentTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:_tablecellIndex];

    NSInteger currentIndex = tableCell.currentCollectionView.contentOffset.x / tableCell.currentCollectionView.frame.size.width;
    tableCell.currentPageControl.currentPage = currentIndex;
}
```

But how do I get the _tablecellIndex?

I tried doing :

```
NSArray *indexes = [self.currentTable visibleCells];
_tablecellIndex = indexes[0];
```

But this is not always true as sometimes the table cells are displayed half and user is swiping second cell.

Comment: cant you have a property of indexpath in uicollectionViewcell. and set this property in cellforrowatindexpath delegate of UITableView

Comment: do you have collection view in each row ?

Comment: Yes I have in each row

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the tableview itself, what indexpath a given cell has.  You do that with this command :

```
[self.formTableView indexPathForCell:myCell];
```

The other problem in your case is that you are within the collection view on the cell, and not within the tableview itself.  So theres a few ways to do that - one nice way is to set up a delegate on the cell that can access the tableview.  Thats a bit involved, so heres an even simpler way (self in this case is the cell object):

```
UITableView *parentTableView = (UITableView*)self.superview;
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [parentTableView indexPathForCell:self];
```

That should do the job.

Comment: But to access the collectionViewCell I need the tableView cell because the collectionView is in tableViewCell.

Comment: Ah ok sorry.  You have the CustomTableCell class, right?  Do the code in that class.  If you dont have an actual header/main for that class, create that first.  Then put the code in there, and you will also naturally have the cell object, as 'self' (apologies if you have already got this - I could do with a look at the entire project really, to see how you have structured it).

Comment: OK Thank you. I will try it out